# Android JPG files to gif

Tags: android, camera, gif, jpeg

Is there any way available to convert jpgs/pngs into a gif image after capturing frames from android?I'm looking for an brief idea or any tutorial links.

Comment: There are really 2 steps to this - reduce color to 8-bit palette and then compress as GIF. There are native code (C) solutions to this that you can link with your app (ndk).